# How to access photos from my Genius G-Shot P7545 camera?

Tags: 10.10, windows, camera

I have a Genius G-Shot P7545 camera. In Windows I had just to plug in the camera to the usb and acces it like a usb stick. I tried to do that in Ubuntu 10.10 with no result. How can I acces the photots?
With these comands I get:

> lsusb
>
> Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
>   Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
>   Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
>   Bus 002 Device 015: ID 0784:1692 Vivitar, Inc.
>   Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
>   Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
>
> sudo fdisk -l
>
> Disk /dev/sda: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
>   255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19457 cylinders
>   Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
>   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   Disk identifier: 0xcf5acf5a
>
> Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
>   /dev/sda1   *           1        2550    20478976   83  Linux
>   /dev/sda3            2550       19458   135810048    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
>   /dev/sda5            2550       19458   135809024   83  Linux
>
> Unable to read /dev/sdb

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason why it shouldn't work, but there have been reports of the device not working from other people. The problem is that no one believes that this single mass storage device just stopped working... it's unbelievable because it's such a standard device.

Does the camera work when you boot up into a LiveCD session? Does it work with an older version of Ubuntu (such as 9.10 / 10/04) It's probably an issue with a new udev rule and I suspect (but have not proven) it's an issue with the modem rule that deals with usb modems that also have disks with windows drivers.

You may end up reporting the bug `ubuntu-bug ubuntu` and trying to get a developer to look into fixing it... if you can convince them.